# Include rows which don't match with IN() clause

Tags: mysql, grafana

I have a table called `log` which contains logs sent by several applications. This table has a `varchar` field called `reference`.

I have a table panel in Grafana in which I show how many logs we have grouped by `reference` values. So the user types one or multiple values in a text field on Grafana like `'ref1', 'ref2', 'ref3'` and a query like this is fired:

```
SELECT reference, count(id)
FROM db.log
WHERE reference IN('ref1', 'ref2', 'ref3')
GROUP BY reference
```

So far so good, it works as intended. What I would like to do is showing a row with `count=0` in case a log with given `reference` doesn't exist. I know I could add arbitrary rows using `UNION` but I think I can't do it in Grafana dynamically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use a query that returns all the values for which you want results and left join the table to aggregate:

```
select t.reference, count(l.id) 
from (
  select 'ref1' reference union all
  select 'ref2' union all
  select 'ref3' 
) t left join db.log l
on l.reference = t.reference
group by t.reference
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=556adc983ac5ca1fdc01618a65aee63e).